# ubercart uc_cart_add_item segment fault 11

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

> http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/uc_cart_add_item/7

when i use the function uc_cart_add_item in my module i got segmentfault 11, but when i use this function in page with php-filter it does not have any problem. any clue please..

```
$regular_count = 2;
if($regular_count > 1) {
  if($discount_exist == FALSE) {
            $data = array("module" => "uc_product");
            $nid = 304;
            $qty = 1;
            uc_cart_add_item($nid, $qty, $data , NULL, TRUE, TRUE,  TRUE);
  }
}
```

When i use this in create-page with php-filter enabled it is working perfectly just for me to test;

But when i use it in my own module i got segmentfault 11 thats the only error.

Do i missed something? like module_load_include, or require_once?

Thank you.